# Dozens of Oblong Green Objects in Google Sky

Tags: sky-survey

In reviewing Google Sky today for the first time, zoomed in at the southern end of the Aquarius constellation, there's dozens of oblong objects, many of which are green. Considering their general uniformity I'm assuming that they are moving objects, meaning the exposure time stretched them out and caused color distortion showing them in green.

Has anyone come across these before and found an explanation as to what they're supposed to be?

Extreme example is 22h17m54.44s - 2°49'58.88" as of May 5, 2020.
Another more typical example is  22h14m58.38s - 3°10'58.58".

[image: Extreme Green Object 1]
[image: Green Object 2]

If you can't see anything green at either of those locations, just zip around. They are all over the place in this area.

Comment: [dammit Elon!](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/545/7982) :-) I can see the headlines now, SpaceX photobombs Google Sky with virtual Starlink satellites because [everything is a simulation](https://www.space.com/41749-elon-musk-living-in-simulation-rogan-podcast.html)